# How should I cite the European Commission?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm using biblatex for reference management in my thesis, and I want to cite [this report from the European Commission](http://bookshop.europa.eu/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/EU-Bookshop-Site/en_GB/-/EUR/ViewPublication-Start?PublicationKey=KINA22039) but I can't figure out what to put in the bib entry. Usually I just find whatever I want to cite on Google Scholar and export the citation, but this document doesn't seem to be catalogued there.

How should the bibliography entry (suitable for bibtex or biblatex) look for the above linked document?

Comment: Biblatex knows `online` type, for web  documents such as a `.pdf` file, most entries valid for `article` or `book` also work for `online`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use whatever entry type you need, so long as you type in correctly the author field

```
author={{The European Commission}},
```

with additional braces. This is the same for `biblatex`/Biber as for BibTeX.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % just for the example

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{eubook,
  author={{The European Commission}},
  title={A title},
  subtitle={A subtitle (optional)},
  year={2014},
  publisher={The European Commission},
  url={http://www.europa.eu/whatever},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

In this document \cite{eubook}, \citeauthor{eubook}
states something.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]